# AutoLayout layoutIfNeeded bounds update time

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, autolayout

I have the following code in my custom UIView. This gets called from `init(frame:)` or `init(coder:)` initializer:

```
   private func setupContentView() {
     contentView = ContentView(frame: .zero)
     contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     addSubview(contentView)
     contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant:thumbWidth).isActive = true
     contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -thumbWidth).isActive = true
     contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
     contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
     contentView.clipsToBounds = true
     contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
     contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
     NSLog("ContentView bounds \(contentView.bounds), view bounds \(self.bounds)")
}
```

I understand that when `layoutIfNeeded` is called, it will update `contentView` frame as soon as it is done. But I do not always see this behaviour. The `NSLog` dump below shows that bounds of `contentView` are still 0 width and 0 height. What am I missing?

```
ContentView bounds (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), view bounds (0.0, 0.0, 774.0, 84.0)
```

Comment: Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false) { (t) in NSLog("ContentView bounds \(contentView.bounds), view bounds \(self.bounds)")} try to make this and you will find both values as same. So as matt says, it take time to fully prepare the layout.

Comment: What is the prescribed maximum delay? The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded) says it is supposed to perform layout *immediately*.

Comment: @DeepakSharma -- *"What am I missing?"* ...  I think the better question is: *"What are **WE** missing (from your code)?"* If I try to guess at what you've left out here: https://pastebin.com/WZ8uDVd5  -- the log output ***DOES*** show the resulting bounds.

Comment: @DonMag What I see in my project is that the superview is first initialized via `init(coder:)` through storyboard and then I call `setupContentView()` in that method. The main contention is whether what I am expecting is realistic or wrong.

Comment: @DeepakSharma - are you asking just because you're curious? Or because you want to do something with the resulting frame/bounds information? If the latter, I think my answer would be: "Don't do that. It's not the correct place to evaluate those values."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom `UIView` subclass does not "exist on its own."

Let's start with a plain "content view" subclass:

```
class ContentView: UIView {
}
```

and we'll define a custom view like this:

```
class YourCustomView: UIView {
    
    var contentView: ContentView!
    let thumbWidth: CGFloat = 40.0
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        print(#function)
        setupContentView()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        print(#function)
        setupContentView()
    }
    
    private func setupContentView() {
        contentView = ContentView(frame: .zero)
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant:thumbWidth).isActive = true
        contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -thumbWidth).isActive = true
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.clipsToBounds = true
        contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
        NSLog("A: ContentView bounds \(contentView.bounds), view bounds \(self.bounds)")

        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        NSLog("B: ContentView bounds \(contentView.bounds), view bounds \(self.bounds)")

        self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
        NSLog("C: ContentView bounds \(contentView.bounds), view bounds \(self.bounds)")
        
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            NSLog("D: ContentView bounds \(self.contentView.bounds), view bounds \(self.bounds)")
        }
    }
    
}
```

Now, in Storyboard, we'll add a `UIView`, assign its class to `YourCustomView`, and give it top/leading/bottom/constraints of `80`:

[image]

When run, we get this output:

```
init(coder:)
A: ContentView bounds (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), view bounds (0.0, 0.0, 233.0, 599.0)
B: ContentView bounds (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), view bounds (0.0, 0.0, 80.0, 0.0)
C: ContentView bounds (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), view bounds (0.0, 0.0, 80.0, 0.0)
D: ContentView bounds (0.0, 0.0, 153.0, 599.0), view bounds (0.0, 0.0, 233.0, 599.0)
```

Next, instead of trailing/bottom constraints, we'll give it explicit width/height constraints:

[image]

Now, when we run it, we get this:

```
init(coder:)
A: ContentView bounds (0.0, 0.0, 120.0, 500.0), view bounds (0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 500.0)
B: ContentView bounds (0.0, 0.0, 120.0, 500.0), view bounds (0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 500.0)
C: ContentView bounds (0.0, 0.0, 120.0, 500.0), view bounds (0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 500.0)
D: ContentView bounds (0.0, 0.0, 120.0, 500.0), view bounds (0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 500.0)
```

As we can see, in the first case - where we set trailing/bottom - during `init(coder)` auto-layout *does not yet know* what the ultimate width and height of `YourCustomView` will be.

In the second case - where we set width/height - during `init(coder)` auto-layout ***does*** already know what the ultimate width and height will be.

Note that if I go back to Storyboard and do my layout with `iPhone SE (1st Generation`:

[image]

and run the app on an `iPhone 14 Pro`, we get this output:

```
init(coder:)
A: ContentView bounds (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), view bounds (0.0, 0.0, 160.0, 388.0)
B: ContentView bounds (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), view bounds (0.0, 0.0, 80.0, 0.0)
C: ContentView bounds (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), view bounds (0.0, 0.0, 80.0, 0.0)
D: ContentView bounds (0.0, 0.0, 153.0, 599.0), view bounds (0.0, 0.0, 233.0, 599.0)
```

Notice that this time the custom view bounds ***starts*** at:

```
(0.0, 0.0, 160.0, 388.0)
```

which it is picking up from my Storyboard layout.

The docs for `.layoutIfNeeded()` say:

> Use this method to force the view to update its layout immediately. When using Auto Layout, the layout engine updates the position of views as needed to satisfy changes in constraints.

The confusion you're running into is that *the rest of the view hierarchy may not be initialized... **and may (will probably) change*** after you make that call.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know what the content view's bounds is going to be after layout, it is not the content view that needs to be laid out but its superview. Change

```
 contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

to

```
 contentView.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Even more reliable, say

```
contentView.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
    NSLog("ContentView bounds \(contentView.bounds), view bounds \(self.bounds)")
}
```

This makes sure that layout has *finished* before you log.

Comment: Both the parts give incorrect results. Even `self.bounds` is incorrect where height is 0.

`ContentView bounds (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), view bounds (0.0, 0.0, 28.0, 0.0)`

Comment: hmmm... if you are getting the bounds in that completion block, isn't the `contentView.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()` superfluous?